# jQuery If/Else not evaluating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to update the coloring with a jQuery if/else, but no matter which way I do it it is only evaluating and applying the first if. If I change all blocks to if, it applied the last if block.

What am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/uJ3D6/3/

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    if ($('.profiletype:contains(Nina)')) {
        $('div.profiletype').css("color", "#ee94ae");
        $('div.sds-usermenu').css("color", "#ee94ae");
    }
    if ($('.profiletype:contains(Chica)')) {
        $('div.profiletype').css("color", "#f7a51c");
        $('div.sds-usermenu').css("color", "#f7a51c");
    }
    if ($('.profiletype:contains(Mujer)')) {
        $('div.profiletype').css("color", "#D31E4B");
        $('div.sds-usermenu').css("color", "#D31E4B");
    }
    if ($('.profiletype:contains(Senora)')) {
        $('div.profiletype').css("color", "#647cbd");
        $('div.sds-usermenu').css("color", "#647cbd");
    }
});
```

Comment: `$('.profiletype:contains(Nina)')` does not return a boolean (`true` or `false`). It returns an object, which is always treated as `true`.

Comment: the fiddle you shared only contained `chica`.. how do you expect the condition to execute upon something that is does not even exist..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$('.profiletype:contains(Nina)')` is an object, so it is always truthy, even if it has length `0`.

If you want to test if the selector matched any elements, then you can use the length property:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    if ($('.profiletype:contains(Nina)').length) {
        $('div.profiletype').css("color", "#ee94ae");
        $('div.sds-usermenu').css("color", "#ee94ae");
    }
    if ($('.profiletype:contains(Chica)').length) {
        $('div.profiletype').css("color", "#f7a51c");
        $('div.sds-usermenu').css("color", "#f7a51c");
    }
    if ($('.profiletype:contains(Mujer)').length) {
        $('div.profiletype').css("color", "#D31E4B");
        $('div.sds-usermenu').css("color", "#D31E4B");
    }
    if ($('.profiletype:contains(Senora)').length) {
        $('div.profiletype').css("color", "#647cbd");
        $('div.sds-usermenu').css("color", "#647cbd");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesn't apply correctly, it applies the last condition regardless of the contains selector. What am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/uJ3D6/6/

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to to test for the existence of an element using jquery, then the code you need to use is :

```
if ($('.profiletype:contains(Nina)')[0]) {
    ...
}
```

This attempts to explore the first element of the DOMElement array that jQuery constructs when it finds elements. if there are none then it evaluates to false.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/vogomatix/uJ3D6/5/

I've changed the colors to make it clearer.... :-)

HTML:

```
<div class="sds-block clearfix profiletype">
   <div class="sds-blockcontent">Chica</div>
</div>
<div class="sds-block clearfix profiletype">
    <div class="sds-blockcontent">Nina</div>
</div>
<div class="sds-block clearfix profiletype">
    <div class="sds-blockcontent">Mujer</div>
</div>
<div class="sds-block clearfix profiletype">
    <div class="sds-blockcontent">Senora</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.profiletype:contains(Nina)').css("color","#ff0000");
    $('.profiletype:contains(Chica)').css("color","#00ff00");
    $('.profiletype:contains(Mujer)').css("color","#0000ff");
    $('.profiletype:contains(Senora)').css("color","#555555");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I had it working when it was a single selector, but once I added the other css and wrapped it in an if it stopped.